# SEO for dynamic content site

Tags: seo

I am hoping there is a simple solution for this simple question. Let's say I have a site like StackOverflow, where new questions are being created everyday by users. What is the SEO strategy to keep the google crawler informed about this new content? Could it be some kind of "LATEST QUESTIONS" page where the new links would be listed? But then the google crawler would have to parse this periodically to fetch new questions. Is there a best practice / industry standard SEO approach for this problem?

Comment: Funny my topic was closed when the tag SEO has 1565 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`sitemap.xml`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) that links to each article.